# Deploy camping app onto heroku?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, heroku, camping

Hello I was wondering how to deploy a camping app onto herokus cedar stack using activerecord and postgresql.

My database.yml:

```
production:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    database: mydb
```

Right now I'm having issues connecting to the database I do have a development database config in the same file.

**UPDATE:**
In response to Johns answer here is the error log heroku is giving me,

```
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `connect'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:12:in `block in <main>'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/src/nuts.rb:8:in `create'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `new'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `table_exists?'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from (eval):20:in `create_schema'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
2012-06-15T20:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will replace your database.yml with their own connected to the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable (typically a postgres database that is provisioned when you setup your application) when you deploy your application to them.

Whats the problem you are seeing?